# Prove $\exp(-|x|^\alpha)$ is integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory

Prove the function
$$x\mapsto\exp(-|x|^\alpha)$$
is $L_p$ integrable $\forall\alpha>0$ (Lebesgue integrable in $\mathbb{R}^p)$

**My attempt:**

If $t < 1$ then $\{x \mid e^{x^\alpha} > t\} = [0,\infty)$.

If $t \ge 1$ then $\{x \mid e^{x^\alpha} > t\} = \{x \mid x^\alpha > \log t\} = ( (\log t)^{1/\alpha},\infty)$.

Here, I'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Comment: The question in the title asks about measurability, and the question in the body asks about integrability. Which is it?

Comment: Use \mapsto for this, not an arrow. It's the preferred notation.

Comment: mistake, sorry @cmk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

Since the function is continuous, it's measurable. To see that it's integrable, switch to polar coordinates:

$$\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-|x|^\alpha}\, dx=\int\limits_{S^{n-1}}\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-r^\alpha}r^{n-1}\, drd\sigma(\omega)
=\text{vol}(S^{n-1})\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-r^\alpha}r^{n-1}\, dr,$$ where $\sigma$ is the surface measure on $S^{n-1}.$ So, it suffices to show that $$\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-r^\alpha}r^{n-1}\, dr<\infty.$$ Can you see that this integral is finite?

EDIT: Here is a sketch of an argument showing that this integral is finite:

Since, for any fixed $\alpha>0,$ $e^{-r^\alpha}r^{n+1}\rightarrow 0$ as $r\rightarrow\infty$, there exists $N$ so that for all $r\geq N,$ we have that $$e^{-r^\alpha}r^{n+1}<1.$$ Hence,

\begin{align*}\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-r^\alpha}r^{n-1}\, dr&=\int\limits_0^Ne^{-r^\alpha}r^{n-1}\, dr+\int\limits_N^\infty e^{-r^\alpha}r^{n-1}\, dr\\
&<\int\limits_0^Ne^{-r^\alpha}r^{n-1}\, dr+\int\limits_N^\infty \frac{1}{r^2}\, dr\\
&<\infty
\end{align*}

Comment: $\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-r^\alpha}r^{n-1}, dr<\infty.$ I can't see why.. Can you be more explicit please?

Comment: @Bvss12 I've added in a sketch for you.

Answer (score 4):

Instead, use composition trick: Let $F(w)=\exp(w)$, $G(t)=-t^{\alpha}$, $H(x)=|x|$ and consider $F\circ G\circ H$, all these are continuous.